# Can I set the encoding of an e-mail message created by AppleScript?

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I have to send a mailing list and want to use Apple Mail for this. I have created a script that reads a UTF8 encoded text file and uses this text to set the contents of the e-mail message. This text is in variable thisText. The code importing the text is similar to

```
set fileHandle to open for access theFile
set mailText to (read fileHandle) as «class utf8»
close access fileHandle
```

After this, I make small adjustments to the text for each recipient and prepare the e-mails with the following code:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
  tell application "Mail"
    set theAccount to "Economy-x-Talk Support"
    set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties ¬
       {account:theAccount, subject:thisSubject, content:thisText, visible:false}
    tell theNewMessage
      make new to recipient at end with properties {address:thisEmail}
      set sender to "Economy-x-Talk Support <xxx@xxxxxxxx.com>"
    end tell
  end tell
end using terms from
```

The problem is that if the text contains special characters, Mail displays them incorrectly. I believe that Mail doesn't understand that the encoding of the message is UTF8. Is there a way to define the encoding of a message when making it? something like:

```
properties {encoding:utf8}
```

perhaps? I tried this and it didn't work. I was unable to find the answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm finding conflicting information over whether or not this works, but try changing your default mail encoding with the following terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NSPreferredMailCharset "UTF-8"
```

Comment: If I put that in a do shell script command at the beginning of my script, what would I have to put at the end of the script to restore the default situation? Would that be "MacRoman"?

Comment: At the beginning of the script, do `set oldEncoding to defaults read com.apple.mail NSPreferredMailCharset`. Then at the end: `"defaults write com.apple.mail" & space & oldEncoding`